# How to make two Forms access the same variables in C++Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

I have two Forms, both are including the same `.cpp` file that has these global variables:

```
static vector<News> allNews;
static vector<user> allUsers;
static admin appAdmin("admin", "adminpassword");
static int userIndex =0;
```

The problem is that, when Form `A` adds `News`  objects to the `vector`, the second Form `B` seems to be viewing a different `vector` that is empty.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Note that this problem is the same in any C++ compiler, it is not specific to C++Builder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*both are including the same .cpp* - never include `.cpp` files. Make a `.h` file with the content:

```
extern vector<News> allNews;
extern vector<user> allUsers;
extern admin appAdmin;
extern int userIndex;
```

And then update the `.cpp` file by removing `static`:

```
vector<News> allNews;
vector<user> allUsers;
admin appAdmin("admin", "adminpassword");
int userIndex = 0;
```

Include the newly created `.h` file into the forms.

---

If you include the `.cpp` file with the `static` variables into two forms, you get two translation units where each of them has their own unique `static` variables, which are not visible to other translation units.